# how does string comparison work using struts2 ognl?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am having 2 string variables '**userType**' and 'isOpened'. The value of **isOpened is 'true' and userType is 'user'**, **both** the values are of **type string**.

when I print this on the JSP I get.

```
<s:property value="%{#session.isProjectOpened}"/>;
<s:property value="%{#session.isProjectOpened.equalsIgnoreCase(true)}"/>;
```

I get both the **values to be true.**

Whereas when i use

```
<s:property value="%{#session.userType}"/>;
<s:property value="%{#session.userType.equalsIgnoreCase(user)}"/>;
```

I get the value **user and false.**

As soon as I make a small change as follows
`<s:property value="%{#session.userType.equalsIgnoreCase('user')}"/>;`

I get the values to be **user and true.**

My Questions are: 
1) Can I use a string 'user' directly like "**equalsIgnoreCase(user)**" without defining the string.

defining the string meaning 
 using `<s:set var="user">user</s:set>`

2) if yes, then can i do it directly like i have done above, or it has to be done using the single quotes like this "**equalsIgnoreCase('user')**"

3) **then how am I getting the value condition to be true, for the 
'isProjectOpened'. Why am I getting one condition to be true and the other to be false**.

Comment: 1. `equalsIgnoreCase(true)` ~> `equalsIgnoreCase(true.toString())` -> `equalsIgnoreCase('true')`. 2. `equalsIgnoreCase(user)` -> `equalsIgnoreCase(user.toString())` -> `equalsIgnoreCase(null)` because you don't have `user` variable.

Comment: so it checks for a variable true to have some value, if there is no value associated with that variable then the boolean value is taken. Am I right?

Comment: `true` is a literal, so it can't be a variable name.

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying

```
<s:property value="%{#session.userType.equalsIgnoreCase(user)}"/>;
```

It means **user** is a variable and if it find the value of variable then only it will be true.

In next place you are using
 `<s:property value="%{#session.userType.equalsIgnoreCase('user')}"/>;`
that is a string(in coat), So that you are getting true as vale.

Answer (score 0):

`user` is a symbol for some object. If you did not define it, it will be treated as `null`.

`'user'` is a String literal.

I don't understand the question about `isProjectOpened`. If that is a String that holds `"true"`, then why would it not print as such? But consider to change it to a `bool` if you can. Better for conditionals.

Comment: isProjectOpened is also a string with value true. when i directly compare the isProjectOpened.equalsIgnoreCase(true) i get it as true, notice true is without the quotes in here. If I add up quotes still i get it to be true. So my question was how can i use the isProjectOpened compared with true equals true and user equals user to be false?

Comment: @anandmohan: Have you seen my comment?